# No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'

Tags: airflow

I am trying to use MysqlOperator of Airflow

While importing

from airflow.providers.mysql.operators.mysql import MySqlOperator

I am getting the following error

No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'

Comment: If you're using an Airflow version 2 or greater you need to explicitly install extras: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/extra-packages-ref.html

Comment: execute  pip freeze and check if the module has been added , otherwise install in from provider package reference page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This fixed it for me, it is also from the official airflow website:**

> You can install this package on top of an existing airflow 2.1+
> installation via `pip install apache-airflow-providers-mysql`

for Python 3 environment use bellow:

```
pip3 install apache-airflow-providers-mysql
```

Comment: In my case running `sudo apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev` prior to installing airflow.providers.mysql worked.

Comment: @shrikanthsingh Yes, this error in normal circumstances doesn't happen, but when it happens it can have many reasons from incompatible versions, ignoring installation pre-requisites that you mentioned and lack of its provider that I've mentioned, thanks.